# Creating a dynamic grid of images in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, multidimensional-array, grid

As part of a project I need to create a dynamic grid of images. This grid will consist of randomly placed images with empty spaces in between. For example:

```
------------------
|Image|Blank|Blank|
|Blank|Image|Image|
|Blank|Image|Blank|
------------------
```

But I'm not sure whats the best way to do this? My idea is two nested for loops e.g.:

```
for ($r = 0; $r <= $rows; $r++)
     for ($c = 0; $c <= $cols; $c++)
         if(isset($data[$r][$c]['Image'])
             echo $data[$r][$c]['Image'];
```

And the data would be in the form:

`$data[row][col][image]`

With `row` and `col` being generated with the PHP `rand` function.

Is this the best way to do this. Or have I overlooked something?

Additionally with this set up how would I update `$data[row][col][image]` when the images are updated?

**Update:**

The output of the grid will look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="RowWrapper>
         <div class="cell">Image</div>
         <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="RowWrapper>
         <div class="cell"></div>
         <div class="cell">Image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is more of a css & js problem.  While traditionally you could generate a grid from a double nested loop you will find that browser rendering is a bit different.

Comment: You want to output this as a bunch of individual images in the browser? Or have the server output ONE image which originally consisted multiple separate smaller images?

Comment: @TheOldOne for simplicity i removed the wrapping divs which would surround the image tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.

http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/jsgrid/